# PHP - Type hint for Laravel Collection or Array

Tags: php, laravel, type-hinting

I would like to create a function which accepts any traversable object as parameter, for example Laravel Collection/Array. Is there any way to type hint this condition in the function parameter??

I want the effect of both the following in single definition:

```
function test(array $traversable)
{
    print_r($traversable);
}
```

AND

```
function test(Illuminate\Support\Collection $traversable)
{
    print_r($traversable);
}
```

AND the DocBlock should be

```
/**
 * Function to do something
 * 
 * @param Collection|Array $traversable Traversable parameter
 * @return null Absolutely nothing
 */
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PHP 7.1 will introduce the `iterable` typehint which will do exactly that:

```
function test(iterable $items) { /*...*/ }
```

See [PHP - rfc:iterable](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/iterable).

Until then you can't use any typehint if you want to accept both `Traversable` and `array`. The only thing you can do is use a proper `@param` annotation to document it:

```
/**
 * @param \Traversable|array $items
 */
function test($items) { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: using PHP 7.4.10 and Laravel 7.28.3:  `dd(collect() instanceof iterable); // false`.  Therefore, I am not able to use iterable to typehint array|Collection

Comment: `iterable` is not a class, so it won't work with `instanceof`. Use `is_iterable()` instead.