# Define type of parameter in method in Laravel as a Collection of Model

Tags: php, laravel-5, collections, type-hinting

In a Laravel 5 class, I want to properly type-hint a method which receives as parameter a collection of `classA` items.

```
public function myMethod( Collection<ClassA> $items ){
    foreach( $items as $item ){
    }
    ...
}
```

How do I declare my variable `$items`?

Is it possible in PHP? (By the way, I am using PHP 7.1)

I found a close answer in [PHP - Type hint for Laravel Collection or Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39406442/php-type-hint-for-laravel-collection-or-array).

However, it is not exactly what I need, because I require the method to accept a Collection of `ClassA` items

Comment: When you say of `classA` items, do you mean of `model` items? E.g. `user` items

Comment: That's not a thing you can do in PHP unfortunately, unless you create a specific `ClassACollection` class which inherits from `Collection`. The language doesn't have a concept of generics.

Comment: Ok, I will take that as the answer. Can you please post it and I will accept it? Thank you.